# conditional-on-positives bias

Tags: causality, bias, selection-bias

I am reading the Bad COP section on https://matheusfacure.github.io/python-causality-handbook/07-Beyond-Confounders.html#bad-cop. I am confused if
$$
E[Y|T = 1] - E[Y|T = 0] = \\ 
E[Y|Y > 0, T = 1]P(Y > 0|T = 1) - E[Y|Y > 0, T = 0]P(Y > 0|T = 0)
$$
is mathematically correct, then why can't we calculate $E[Y|Y > 0, T = t]$ and $P(Y > 0|T = t)$ separately before multiplying them and subtraction to calculate the ATE? What is the COP bias and what exactly is not allowed?